# passing data to modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

After checking Google for a long time, I can't find a solution:

A link like this:

```
<%= link_to instruction.name, "#myModal", :data => {:toggle => "modal",\
:id => instruction.id}, :class=> "openModal"%>
```

should open a modal window and show the complete Instruction data.
What is the best solution using coffeescript?

I can manage to show the id within a span tag. 
But how to get the id in a `Function.find(:id)`?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

o.k. nobody anwered... found myself:

the view:

```
<%= link_to instruction.name, "#myModal", :data => {:toggle => "modal", :href => instruction_path(instruction)},  :class=> "openModal"%>
```

Coffee:

```
$(document).on "click", ".openModal", ->
$(".modal-body").load($(this).data('href'))
```

Works with Twitter bootstrap